# Rails turbo visit without change history state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo-rails

I want to trigger a get request cycle without change in browser history. I have tried

```
Turbo.visit(url, { action: "advance" });
Turbo.visit(url, { action: "replace" });
```

But both change history.

Comment: I have found a workaround Turbo.visit(url, { action: "" }); but this is not clean. Turbo should provide a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do the following:

`Turbo.visit(url, { historyChanged: true });`

This takes into account that the history was already changed and it will skip the step of updating the browser history.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the action option with visit to trigger a get request cycle without changing browser history. visit(url, { action "advance" }) visit(url, { action "replace" })

Comment: Thanks, both of the above actions changing browser history.